# Invalid IP Address exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ip-address, ping

I'm working on a small C# project, but i have some troubles converting string to `IPAddress`. Here's the code :

```
Ping pingeage = new Ping();
String ip = tabtempsoctets1[0] 
    + "." + tabtempsoctets1[1] 
    + "." + tabtempsoctets1[2] 
    + "." + tabtempsoctets1[3];
MessageBox.Show(ip);
IPAddress adresseTest = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
boxLogs.Text = adresseTest.ToString();
PingReply reponse = pingeage.Send(adresseTest,2000);
```

But VisualStudio raise an exception, telling me that my `IpAddress` is not an `IPAddress`.
Why?
`tabtempoctets1` is an array of string, and i manually added the `"."`
What's wrong in here ?

Comment: What is the value of `ip`, your string

Comment: First guess would be one of the entries is not between 0-255.

Comment: The mesage box displays it like "127.1.1.1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you have leading or trailing space(s). Otherwise it should successfully parse `"127.1.1.1"` try:

```
IPAddress adresseTest = IPAddress.Parse(ip.Trim());
```

You can also try `IPAddress.TryParse` which would not raise an exception in case parsing fails. Like:

```
string str = "     127.1.1.1       ";
IPAddress a;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(str.Trim(), out a))
{
    //parsing succesful
}
else
{
    //invalid string
}
```

You may also use `string.Join` to concatenate your string like:

```
string ip = string.Join(".", tabtempsoctets1);
```

Comment: That's it ! Thanks ! Working perfectly

Comment: @user2564494, glad it did

Comment: @user2564494, also its better if you use `string ip = string.Join(".", tabtempsoctets1);` for ip string, less lines of code :)

Answer (score 1):

With the strings set correctly `string[] tabtempsoctets1 = { "127", "1", "1", "1" };` the code above appears to work for me.

You might try converting to a byte array to check the range.

Here is the test app I used successfully on my Win7 PC

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IPAddressTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] tabtempsoctets1 = { "127", "1", "1", "1" };
        Ping pingeage = new Ping();
        //Ping pingeage = new Ping();
        String ip = tabtempsoctets1[0]
            + "." + tabtempsoctets1[1]
            + "." + tabtempsoctets1[2]
            + "." + tabtempsoctets1[3];
        Console.WriteLine(ip);
        IPAddress adresseTest = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        Console.WriteLine(adresseTest.ToString());

        byte [] addressAsBytes = new byte[tabtempsoctets1.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tabtempsoctets1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!byte.TryParse(tabtempsoctets1[i], out addressAsBytes[i]))
                Console.WriteLine(tabtempsoctets1[i] + " is not formated correctely");
        }
        IPAddress adresseTest2 = new IPAddress(addressAsBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(adresseTest2.ToString());
        PingReply reponse = pingeage.Send(adresseTest2, 2000);
        Console.WriteLine(reponse.Status.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] tabtempsoctets1 = new string[] { "127", "1", "1", "1" }; 

        Ping pingeage = new Ping();
        String ip = tabtempsoctets1[0]
            + "." + tabtempsoctets1[1]
            + "." + tabtempsoctets1[2]
            + "." + tabtempsoctets1[3];
        MessageBox.Show(ip);
        IPAddress adresseTest = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
       // boxLogs.Text = adresseTest.ToString();
        PingReply reponse = pingeage.Send(adresseTest, 2000);

         works for me
```